# Copy to new or existing struct from another struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I'm getting in touch with C for about a month and I'm trying to get a more enhanced example of the use of struct and `malloc` for myself and for educational purposes.

What I really want to do is to make deep copy of struct element:

1. into a new object
2. into an existing object

Way to go:

```
1)
1.1_ allocate memory for struct
1.2_ allocate memory for type
1.3_ allocate memory for 2d array data

2)
2.1 free memory of 2d array data with (free)
2.2 free memory of type
2.3 same steps as new object
```

**Functions I want to make**

```
Element element copyToNewObject (Element _element)
{
    /*No idea how to start */
}

Element element copyToExistingObject (Element _element)
{
    /*No idea how to start */   
}


// Type Element
typedef struct element * Element;
```

**My Struct Element:**

```
struct element {
        char* type; /* 2 charactere*/
        int i;
        int j;
        int **data;/* 2d array of i and j */
};
```

**Function call in main**

```
Element element  = initElement();
```

**Function body**

```
Element initElement(void) {

    Element _element = (Element) malloc(sizeof(Element));   

    int position;

    if(_element == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;   
    }   

    (_element)->type = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));

    if((_element)->type == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;   
    }

    element->data = malloc(element->i * sizeof(int *));

    if(element->data == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;    
    }   
    for( position = 0; position < (element->j) ; position++)
       (element)->data[position] = malloc((element)->j * sizeof(int));

    return _element;
}
```

Comment: `initElement` is completely wrong. I would recommend focusing on getting that right before you go onto worrying about making a copy. I'd also suggest learning from a book or other reference.

Comment: In your `initElement` function the variable `_element` is not a pointer. It's an *instance* of the structure. It has been allocated by the compiler. Also note that strings are really called ***null terminated** byte strings*. A string containing two characters needs three bytes allocated for it. And if the string will *always* have the same size, why not simply make it an array of characters?

Comment: If you want a 2D array in C, use a single `malloc()` or `calloc()` call, NOT a malloc of one array of pointers followed by N mallocs of the second dimension.

Comment: The header is more like struct element initElement (struct element* _element)

Comment: Also, remember that casting the value returned by `malloc` is bad, m'kay?

Comment: I make changes now, it initElement ok

Comment: @DavidEdgar it's still completly wrong and it won't compile. Read about pointers first and understand that concept.

Comment: I really don't undestand, the teacher use this logic and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Element* copyToNewObject (Element* origin)
{

    if (!origin)
        return NULL;

    Element* target = malloc(sizeof(*target));

    target->type = malloc(sizeof(*(target->type)) * 3) //which should be 3 chars as specified by Some programmer dude
    *(target->type)     = *(origin->type);
    *(target->type + 1) = *(origin->type + 1);
    *(target->type + 2) = '\0';

    target->i = origin->i;
    target->j = origin->j;

    //declare data
    target->data = malloc((sizeof(*(target->data)) * target->i) + (target->j * target->i * sizeof(**(target->data));

    //point the set of row pointers to their respective rows
    size_t k;
    int* rowpointer = target->data + target->i;
    for (k = 0; k < target->i; k++)
        *(target->data + k) = rowpointer + (k * target->j);

    //copy the data
    for (k = 0; k < i; k++)
        memcpy(*(target->data + k), *(origin->data + k), j);

    return target;

}

void copyToExistingObject (Element* origin, Element* target)
{
    //Same as copyToNewObject but without the delcaration of target or the malloc-ing of the target fields
}
```

Also, since we're using `malloc` we subsequently need to use `free` as well.

```
void ElementFree(Element* element)
{
    free(element->type);
    free(element->data);
    free(element);
}
```